# mvc route for controller actions only

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am setting an mvc route to catch 404's. I don't want this route to be called when its not a request to controller action eg request for an image should not trigger the route if the image is not found.

Answer (score 0):

You can cahnge IIS configuration to not handle the .jpg or any other file format that you don't want your application to process or you can add a IgnoreRoute (in App_start/RouteConfig (depends of your MVC version) to the routes for every type of files you don't want to be process.

Like this :

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");
routes.IgnoreRoute("*.jpg");
routes.MapRoute("CatchAll", "{*path}", [Page404ControllerAction]);
```

Hope it helps!